# Class method or field in a different namespace?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to set a different namespace for a single class method or field?

```
class A{
public:
  void m1();
  void m2(); // this in diff namespace, how?
  void m3();
}
```

Comment: @texasbruce really? :O

Comment: I suppose this only makes sense for static member functions.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/201677). Can you elaborate on why you want this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: no. Namespaces contain classes, and non-class functions or class instances.

Comment: Or namespaces, or structs, or constants, or enumerations, or aliases, etc. Namespaces are not about classes and never will be.

Answer (score 1):

You may not nest plain namespaces (i.e., the `namespace` keyword) into classes, but you can use other stuff inside a class that also acts as a namespace, such as an inner `class` or an inner `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an inner class as a pseudo-namespace:

```
class A
{
   public:
     void m1();
     struct B
     {
         void m2();
     };
     void m3();
};
```

Comment: It would make more sense if `m2()` were `static`.